# Match only a given type of characters

Tags: regex

Is it possible to match only a given type of characters in a string. The strings looks like this:

```
^55555555$
^5 55 555 555  $
^  5    55  555   555  $
```

I need a Regex which matches a given amount of numbers e.g. `{5,10}` and ignores the characters in between.

Is it possible to define such a Regex?

Regards,
Reto

Comment: Can't you simply count matches? For example, a regex "`5`" should return 8, 9 and 9 matches respectively for each string you posted. If you need more characters to be included, simply use character class (`[ ]`).

Or better yet, use your programming language's (most probably) built-in feature of counting given characters in a string, or write one yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll use this regex within an appliance and this test only for match or don't match...

Comment: *"and ignores the characters in between."* -- a regular expression always matches a set of consecutive characters of a string (it can be the entire string or just a fragment of it). It can match multiple substrings but they are different matches. Your question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a regex which is doing what I need:

```
^\s*([5]\s*){5,10}$
```

It is true for the following examples:

```
^55555555$
^5 55 555 555  $
^  5    55  555   555  $
```

But false for the following:

```
^6666666$
^5 55 5  $
^  5    55  555   555  5555 $
```

The part `[5]` can be replaced by any characters which should be found...

Comment: `[5]` is the same thing as `5`.